# Problem using Simpson's integration rule in GAMS

Tags: gams-math, simpsons-rule

I have made a simple code using GAMS which determines the maximum reach of a glider using trapeziod integration. I want to recreate the same program with SImpson's integration, however, I cannot understand the results.

This is the functional code with the trapezoid rule:

```
$set n 50
set j /0*%n%/;
sets
jlast(j)
jnotlast(j);
jlast(j)$(ord(j)=card(j))=yes;
jnotlast(j)=not jlast(j);
scalar
n number of intervals /%n%/
m mass /5000/
S surface /21.55/
CD0 drag /0.023/
k ni idea /0.073/
hmax initial height /1000/
g gravity /9.81/

density density /1.225/
variable
gamma(j),
CL(j),
D(j),
CD(j),
L(j),
*x(j),
*y(j),
objective;

positive variable

x(j),
y(j),
v(j),

step;

equation
diffx(j),
diffy(j),
valueD(j),
valueL(j),
obj;

 diffx[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. x[j+1]-x[j] =e=0.5*step*(v(j+1)*cos(gamma(j+1)) +  v(j)*cos(gamma(j))   );
 diffy[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. y[j+1]-y[j] =e=0.5*step*(v(j+1)*sin(gamma(j+1)) +  v(j)*sin(gamma(j))   );

valueD[j].. m*g*sin(gamma(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v(j)*v(j)*(CD0+k*CL(j)*CL(j));
valueL[j].. m*g*cos(gamma(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v(j)*v(j)*CL(j);

obj .. objective =e=   x('%n%');





x.fx('0') = 1.0e-12;
y.fx('0') = 1000;
y.fx('%n%') = 1.0e-12;

CL.up(j) =1.4;

y.up (j) = 1000;

gamma.up(j) = pi*0.5;


v.lo(j) =  1.0e-12;


y.lo(j) = 1.0e-12;


CL.lo(j) = 0;

gamma.lo(j) = 0;



model brahstron1 /all/;

option
nlp=ipopt;
solve brahstron1 using nlp maximize objective;
```

And this is the defective one using Simpson:

```
$set n 50
set j /0*%n%/;
sets
jlast(j)
jnotlast(j);
jlast(j)$(ord(j)=card(j))=yes;
jnotlast(j)=not jlast(j);
scalar
n number of intervals /%n%/
m mass /5000/
S surface /21.55/
CD0 drag /0.023/
k ni idea /0.073/
hmax initial height /1000/
g gravity /9.81/

density density /1.225/
variable
gamma(j),
CL(j),
D(j),
CD(j),
L(j),

gamma_med(j),
CL_med(j),
D_med(j),
CD_med(j),
L_med(j),

objective;

positive variable

x(j),
y(j),
v(j),

x_med(j),
y_med(j),
v_med(j),

step;

equation
diffx(j),
diffy(j),
diffx_central(j),
diffy_central(j),
valueD(j),
valueL(j),
valueD_central(j),
valueL_central(j),
obj;


diffx[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. x[j+1]-x[j] =e=(1/6)*step*(v(j+1)*cos(gamma(j+1)) +  v(j)*cos(gamma(j)) + 4*v_med(j+1)*cos(gamma_med(j+1))  );
diffy[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. y[j+1]-y[j] =e=(1/6)*step*(v(j+1)*sin(gamma(j+1)) +  v(j)*sin(gamma(j)) +  4*v_med(j+1)*sin(gamma_med(j+1))  );

diffx_central[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. x_med[j+1] =e=0.5*(x(j+1)+x(j));
diffy_central[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. y_med[j+1] =e=0.5*(y(j+1)+y(j));


valueD[j].. m*g*sin(gamma(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v(j)*v(j)*(CD0+k*CL(j)*CL(j));
valueL[j].. m*g*cos(gamma(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v(j)*v(j)*CL(j);

valueD_central[j].. m*g*sin(gamma_med(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v_med(j)*v_med(j)*(CD0+k*CL_med(j)*CL_med(j));
valueL_central[j].. m*g*cos(gamma_med(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v_med(j)*v_med(j)*CL_med(j);

obj .. objective =e=   x('%n%');




x.fx('0') = 1.0e-12;
y.fx('0') = 1000;
y.fx('%n%') = 1.0e-12;

CL.up(j) =1.4;
CL_med.up(j) =1.4;

y.up (j) = 1000;
y_med.up (j) = 1000;

gamma.up(j) = pi*0.5;
gamma_med.up(j) = pi*0.5;

v.lo(j) =  1.0e-12;
v_med.lo(j) =  1.0e-12;

y.lo(j) = 1.0e-12;
y_med.lo(j) = 1.0e-12;


CL.lo(j) = 0;
CL_med.lo(j) =0;

gamma.lo(j) = 0;
gamma_med.lo(j) = 0;


model brahstron1 /all/;
* Invoke the LGO solver option for solving this nonlinear programming
option
nlp=ipopt;
solve brahstron1 using nlp maximize objective;
```

What I did was to follow the book

*Practical Methods for Optimal Control and Estimation Using Nonlinear Programming* between pages 141 and 142. Since my control is unknown the y_hat are simply the average of the sum of y_k+1 and y_k, then, I defined the variables D and L at these points and then calculated y_k+1 - y_k how it is sugested in page 141.

However, instead of seeing the variables displayed as in the first code, now I see some kind of weird loop. [This is my propper answer with trapezoid rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucj3A.png)
[and this is my defective solution with Simpson's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LXEf.png).

All recomendations on where my error or errors are are extremely welcome.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After triyng for some time, I have found out that it is a licence problem what is causing these issues. A simple change in the code enables it to work as it should.

```
$set n 10
set j /0*%n%/;
sets
jlast(j)
jnotlast(j);
jlast(j)$(ord(j)=card(j))=yes;
jnotlast(j)=not jlast(j);
scalar
n number of intervals /%n%/
m mass /5000/
S surface /21.55/
CD0 drag /0.023/
k ni idea /0.073/
hmax initial height /1000/
g gravity /9.81/

density density /1.225/
variable
gamma(j),
CL(j),
D(j),
CD(j),
L(j),

gamma_med(j),
CL_med(j),
D_med(j),
CD_med(j),
L_med(j),

objective;

positive variable

x(j),
y(j),
v(j),

x_med(j),
y_med(j),
v_med(j),

step;

equation
diffx(j),
diffy(j),
diffx_central(j),
diffy_central(j),
valueD(j),
valueL(j),
valueD_central(j),
valueL_central(j),
obj;


diffx[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. x[j+1]-x[j] =e=(1/6)*step*(v(j+1)*cos(gamma(j+1)) +  v(j)*cos(gamma(j)) + 4*v_med(j+1)*cos(gamma_med(j+1))  );
diffy[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. y[j+1]-y[j] =e=(-1)* (1/6)*step*(v(j+1)*sin(gamma(j+1)) +  v(j)*sin(gamma(j)) +  4*v_med(j+1)*sin(gamma_med(j+1))  );

diffx_central[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. x_med[j+1] =e=0.5*(x(j+1)+x(j)+(step/8)*(v_med(j)*cos(gamma_med(j)))-(v_med(j+1)*cos(gamma_med(j+1))));
diffy_central[j]$(jnotlast(j)).. y_med[j+1] =e=0.5*(y(j+1)+y(j)+(step/8)*(v_med(j)*sin(gamma_med(j)))-(v_med(j+1)*sin(gamma_med(j+1))));


valueD[j].. m*g*sin(gamma(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v(j)*v(j)*(CD0+k*CL(j)*CL(j));
valueL[j].. m*g*cos(gamma(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v(j)*v(j)*CL(j);

valueD_central[j].. m*g*sin(gamma_med(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v_med(j)*v_med(j)*(CD0+k*CL_med(j)*CL_med(j));
valueL_central[j].. m*g*cos(gamma_med(j))=e=0.5*density*S*v_med(j)*v_med(j)*CL_med(j);

obj .. objective =e=   x('%n%');




x.fx('0') = 1.0e-12;
y.fx('0') = 1000;
y.fx('%n%') = 1.0e-12;

CL.up(j) =1.4;
CL_med.up(j) =1.4;

y.up (j) = 1000;
y_med.up (j) = 1000;

gamma.up(j) = pi*0.5;
gamma_med.up(j) = pi*0.5;

gamma.lo(j) = 0;
gamma_med.lo(j) = 0;

v.lo(j) =  1.0e-12;
v_med.lo(j) =  1.0e-12;

y.lo(j) = 1.0e-12;
y_med.lo(j) = 1.0e-12;


CL.lo(j) = 0;
CL_med.lo(j) =0;

gamma.lo(j) = 0;
gamma_med.lo(j) = 0;


model brahstron1 /all/;
* Invoke the LGO solver option for solving this nonlinear programming
option
nlp=ipopt;
solve brahstron1 using nlp maximize objective;
```